# Generating PlotLabel with mathematical formatting

Tags: plotting, boxes

What's a good pattern to insert properly formatted matrices into `PlotLabel`? I'm trying to insert something like the following into my plot, where the matrix is programmatically generated.

$$
f(x,y)=
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
x&y
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1.00 & 0.00 \\
 0.00 & 2.00 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 x \\
 y \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Doing `PlotLabel->MatrixForm[mymatrix]` displays the matrix part properly, but how do I concatenate it with the other bits?

```
rotatedAxes[angle_] := (
   H = With[{r = RotationMatrix[Pi/4]}, 
     r . DiagonalMatrix[{1, 2}] . Inverse[r]];
   f[{x_, y_}] = {x, y} . H . {x, y};
   
   rotmat = RotationMatrix[angle];
   xaxis = rotmat . {5, 0};
   yaxis = rotmat . {0, 5};
   Hdisp = 
    Map[NumberForm[#, {3, 2}] &, 
      N[Inverse[rotmat] . H . rotmat], {2}] // MatrixForm;
   
   ContourPlot[f[{x, y}], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
    ContourShading -> None, Contours -> 15, 
    ContourStyle -> Directive[RGBColor[0.5, 0.5, 1]], Frame -> None, 
    AxesStyle -> Directive[Black],
    Epilog -> {
      AxisObject[InfiniteLine[{{0, 0}, xaxis}], {-1, 1}, 
       TickLabels -> None], 
      AxisObject[InfiniteLine[{{0, 0}, yaxis}], {-1, 1}, 
       TickLabels -> None]},
    PlotLabel -> Hdisp
    ]
   );
rotatedAxes[Pi/4]
```

[image]

Comment: Something like this? ``mat = RandomInteger[5, {2, 2}] // MatrixForm; row = {{x, y}} // MatrixForm; col = {{x}, {y}} // MatrixForm; Plot[x, {x, -3, 3}, PlotLabel -> Row[{HoldForm[f[x, y]], " = ", row , mat, col}]]``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

rotatedAxes[angle_] := (H = With[{r = RotationMatrix[Pi/4]},
     r . DiagonalMatrix[{1, 2}] . Inverse[r]];
   f[{x_, y_}] = {x, y} . H . {x, y};
   rotmat = RotationMatrix[angle];
   xaxis = rotmat . {5, 0};
   yaxis = rotmat . {0, 5};
   Hdisp = Map[NumberForm[#, {3, 2}] &,
      N[Inverse[rotmat] . H . rotmat], {2}] //
     MatrixForm;
   ContourPlot[f[{x, y}], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
    ContourShading -> None,
    Contours -> 15,
    ContourStyle -> Directive[RGBColor[0.5, 0.5, 1]],
    Frame -> None,
    AxesStyle -> Directive[Black],
    Epilog -> {
      AxisObject[InfiniteLine[{{0, 0}, xaxis}], {-1, 1},
       TickLabels -> None],
      AxisObject[InfiniteLine[{{0, 0}, yaxis}], {-1, 1},
       TickLabels -> None]},
    PlotLabel -> StringForm["`` = (``  ``) `` ``\n",
      HoldForm[f[x, y]],
      Style["x", Italic],
      Style["y", Italic],
      Hdisp,
      MatrixForm[{x, y}]]]);

rotatedAxes[Pi/4]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, `StringForm` seems like a cool thing to know about

Answer (score 0):

```
rotatedAxes[
   angle_] := (H = 
    With[{r = RotationMatrix[Pi/4]}, 
     r . DiagonalMatrix[{1, 2}] . Inverse[r]];
   f[{x_, y_}] = {x, y} . H . {x, y};
   rotmat = RotationMatrix[angle];
   xaxis = rotmat . {5, 0};
   yaxis = rotmat . {0, 5};
   Hdisp = 
    Map[NumberForm[#, {3, 2}] &, 
      N[Inverse[rotmat] . H . rotmat], {2}] // MatrixForm;
   pe = Text@
     Style[TraditionalForm[" = "], 16, Red, FontFamily -> "Times"];
   p2 = Text@
     Style[TraditionalForm[Defer@f[x, y]], 16, Red, 
      FontFamily -> "Times"];
   p3 = Text@
     Style[TraditionalForm[f[x, y] = {{x, y}} . Hdisp . {{x}, {y}}], 
      16, Red, FontFamily -> "Times"];
   ContourPlot[f[{x, y}], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
    ContourShading -> None, Contours -> 15,
    ContourStyle -> Directive[RGBColor[0.5, 0.5, 1]], Frame -> None,
    AxesStyle -> Directive[Black],
    PlotLabel -> 
     Apply[StringJoin, ToString[#, StandardForm] & /@ {p2, pe, p3}]
    (*Epilog\[Rule]{AxisObject[InfiniteLine[{{0,0},xaxis}],{-1,1},
    TickLabels\[Rule]None],AxisObject[InfiniteLine[{{0,0},yaxis}],{-1,
    1},TickLabels\[Rule]None]}]*)]);

rotatedAxes[Pi/12]
```

Some objects on your plot such as AxisObject are not available on my system. The screen shot shows that and the lines are not rendered. But it works still with the plot label and calculation. I think it will work on your setup.

[image]

Comment: `AxisObject` is new on `12.3.1`. This works, although seems more complicated than `StringForm`

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov There is always something to learn.